# SSH tunneling, HTTP correct response to correct client

Tags: http, ssh-tunnel

I am using SSH port forwarding to relay HTTP traffic from personal computers of trusted remote clients to a localhost server running on a computer behind my company proxy. This computer behind the company proxy is not directly accessible to remote clients.

Here is the setup : I setup a Linux VM with a public IP address and only one port open for SSH. For security I disabled root login and password login. The remote clients send me their public SSH key and I add them to the "authorized_keys" file on the Linux VM.

Now I ask the client to use SSH local port forwarding to forward one of their local port (say 453) to a port on the Linux VM (say 345). So basically they "upload" all the traffic going to their local port 453 to the port 345 of the Linux VM. On the company PC, I use SSH remote port forwarding to "download" all the traffic from the port 345 of the Linux VM to the localhost server port (say 9999).

This way I can relay their HTTP traffic securely without giving them access to my company PC. I have tested this approach and its working fine. I can get HTTP request from my remote client and the client also gets back the response.

But I was thinking of the case of multiple remote clients from different computers. Each client will have a SSH tunnel to the same port of the Linux VM. Each of them will "upload" HTTP traffic from their local port 453 to the port 345 of the Linux VM. So while giving back the response (from my localhost server on company PC), is it guaranteed that the response for a particular request goes back to the correct client who sent the request?

I read something about HTTP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260983/how-does-http-response-get-sent-back-to-correct-client-in-tcp). But I was not sure if its also correct for the SSH case with multiple tunnels from different clients.

Can someone comment on whether or not the traffic from different clients be scrambled so that the response which was supposed to go to client A actually goes to client B?

If yes, how can I avoid this?

Comment: There's an "answer" (but not really an answer) from "Linux_newbie". If it's from you then I can see you have created at least two unregistered accounts. The new account does not own the question. Please follow [*I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?*](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) After you regain ownership of the question you will be able to [edit] it freely and to post comments here.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple connections to one end of the tunnel will generate multiple connections from the other end of the tunnel. These connections will not mix.

When a client connects to their end of their tunnel, the IP address and port of the end are fixed, as well as their browser IP address. Still their browser can (and will) bind to *different* ports while creating these connections. This way the connections will be perfectly distinguishable from one another. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1451814/432690).

The process repeats on the VM. Different connections (from the same or different clients, it doesn't matter) will target the same IP address and port of the remote end of your tunnel, coming from the same machine (the said VM), so probably from the same IP address; but even then they will be distinguishable by at least the ports they bind to.

And again on the local end of your tunnel there will be different connections to be established to the HTTP server with fixed IP address and port, but they will use different ports on their "source" end.

So the same mechanism works three times independently in the process of connecting one client to the HTTP server in question. Each time it's the respective OS's job to assign [an *unused* port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65477/108618) for a process that wants to initiate a connection. (A tool that initiates a connections can request a specific port and sometimes get it; but in this case there is no point and the respective tools most likely don't even try, they accept whatever "random" port the OS assigns to them.)

There is no way traffic from (or to) different clients gets scrambled. Frankly, it would be a non-trivial task to scramble it *on demand*.

Distinguishing solely by a port number limits the number of connections that can be handled at any given time. But even if the limit is reached, new connections will be denied rather than mixed with already existing ones. Ports no longer in use can be reused, so terminated connections will make room for new ones.

---

Side note: in general a HTTP server may reject URLs it doesn't consider as its own. If this is an issue and you cannot reconfigure the HTTP server, then any client in question should use the right URL and make sure on their own the traffic gets to their end of their tunnel on their local computer anyway.