# Multiple Processes listening on Port 22? How is this possible?

Tags: networking, unix, process, port, sockets

I have a Solaris 10 Server that has SSH enabled, I wanted to find out which specific process is responsible for opening the socket that listens for the port 22. I used the `PFiles` utility to loop over all the processes in the `/proc` folder to  find this out using the simple script below:

```
PORT=22; for PID in /proc/*; do pfiles ${PID} |grep "port: ${PORT}" && echo ${PID}; done
```

What I found out was there are multiple processes listening to this same port. Sample output is below:

```
   sockname: AF_INET6 ::ffff:10.192.18.188  port: 22 /proc/26766
   sockname: AF_INET6 ::ffff:10.192.18.188  port: 22 /proc/26767
   sockname: AF_INET6 ::  port: 22 /proc/620
   sockname: AF_INET6 ::ffff:10.192.18.188  port: 22  /proc/9131
   sockname: AF_INET6 ::ffff:10.192.18.188  port: 22 /proc/9132
```

My question is, how is this possible? Can multiple processes listen for the same port on the same IP address? And if this is possible, do all this process IDs share a single socket that is bound to this address:port or have multiple sockets open each of which listens on the same address:port, and the kernel decides which socket to pass the connection to at a specific moment in time? Can someone kindly clarify? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know Solaris and I don't know if the output you provided indicates *listening* processes. But if it does, then see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1267230/432690) which applies to Linux. Solaris is not Linux. I have found some sources that say `SO_REUSEPORT` was not supported in Solaris at the time they were written, but they are old. I'm not able to confirm the current status. Still this may advance your own research.

Comment: Do not mistake **established** connection on port 22 with **listening** connection on port 22. only one process at a time can do later while many can do former.

Comment: You guys are right. `PFiles` was possibly showing Listening Ports as well as Established Connection Ports of a Process. I'll have to re-run the utility in the Server and check. Thanks for your time!